# Weird alarm sounding on my computer when under load, but no overheating

Tags: memory, graphics-card, cpu, power-supply, alarm

I am having a rather odd hardware issue and to be honest, I am not quite sure what is causing it. I have been building my own systems for over 10 years and have all kinds of qualifications, but this one has me completely stumped.

Pretty much what is happening is whenever my system is under load, I am getting some kind of "bios alarm" from what sounds like my graphics card. This happens when I am rendering video in Premiere or playing intensive games with the graphics settings up high.

I am rendering a video right now and the alarm is sounding, but my CPU temperature is only 63 Celsius (from CoreTemp) and my video card temperature (gotten from GPU Temp) is 67 Celsius.

If it's not an overheating issue, I cannot fathom what could be causing the alarm. Could anyone offer any insight?

Here are my full system specs:

- CPU: AMD Phenom II X6 1100BT
- GPU: Gainward GeForce 560TI, 1024mb GDDR
- RAM: 16gb Kingston HyperX (2x8gb, Model KHX1600C10D3B1/8G)
- PSU: Chieftech CFT-650-14CS
- HDD: I have 5 hard drives in total. 1x4tb, 1x2tb, 1x1tb, and 2x500gb.
- Optical: LG Blu-Ray Burner.
- Cooling: Corsair H70 Watercooling, 2 additional 12cm fans.

I really cannot determine what is causing the alarm. I am pretty sure it's not a power issue as it's a pretty beefy power supply.

Thoughts?

If you require more info, please inform me, and I'll reply.

Thanks

Comment: Do you get the same alarm from the system if you intentionally unhook the AUX power from the video card?

Comment: I'll test when I am done rendering video in around 30 minutes

Comment: Please report about software you are using to check temperatures.

Comment: As stated above I am using CoreTemp and GPU Temp

Comment: watercooling, some people have motors for the pump that the RPM speed is rather low, when working all properly. An adjustment of the "fan Speed" parameters in the bios or uefi was needed.  Exmaples the RPM low is default set to 600RPM , and the pump was below that, so they changed the default low for the fan speed monitoring.  Can't see how that happens when it should be running at a high speed when needing cooling, but it is one more possible.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I disconnected my aux power from the card and did not get any alarms. Regarding my water cooling, its cooling the system properly. Its not over-heating even when at load. There must be another issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Overheating** is, of course, the main reason for alarms beeping.
**Fans** moving too slow is the other.
**Voltage** overload is the third I can think about, yet I don't know for sure of any motherboard that has this capability.
Maybe you are missing some info in your sensors software.
I suggest for you to check sensors (*temps, fans and voltages*) using:

- **[AIDA64](http://www.aida64.com/)**  , if you run Windows.
- "**sensors**", from "lm-sensors" Debian package, if you run Linux (if someone knows about a better software, please report!).

Many sensors are only detected by highly specialised software. **AIDA64** is the best, as far as I know (if someone know about a better software, please report too!):

[image]

It is not free software as for now, but you can download a fully functional 30 day trial version from [their site](http://www.aida64.com/downloads)  (any version should work; I prefer *Business*, for their capabilty to remote management, but here you have the [comparison between versions](http://www.aida64.com/product/aida64-extreme-edition/features).
If possible, report what happent. It could be useful for some of us.

Comment: I installed this software and every sensor is reporting good temperatures.

Comment: Any info about **voltages**? It is not easy to know when they are not in their appropriate interval, but maybe you could search for peaks in data readings.